# Conditional probability question with three independent events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following probabilities:

$$P(A_1)= P(A_2) = P(A_3)= .2,$$
where $A_1, A_2,$ and $A_3$ are all independent.

I wish to find
$$P(A_1\mid A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3).$$

I know that
$$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) = 3(.2) - 3(.2)(.2) + (.2)(.2)(.2) = .488.$$

I do not know how to proceed after this, however.  I do not understand how to incorporate the conditional part of the problem into my answer.

Any guidance is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but if we use the conditional probability formula $P(A_1\mid A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)=\frac{P(A_1 \cap (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3))}{P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)}=\frac{P(A_1)}{P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)}$

Comment: @MathLasker Be sure.  That's how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition of Conditional Probability, and the fact that $A_1\subseteq A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$.

$$\mathsf P(A_1\mid A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A_1)}{\mathsf P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)}=\dfrac{0.200}{0.488}$$

Comment: Great, brief answer- right to the point.  I guess I am just confused as to why the conditional probability simplifies to $P(A_1)$?

Comment: As said, since $A_1\subseteq A_1\cup X$, therefore $A_1\cap (A_1\cup X)= A_1$.